# Simplest example of ansible aws_s3 get_url operation

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

Trying to get a simple example of mode `geturl` in ansible module `aws_s3`. I tried searching online but didn't see any help.

Went through the official doc as well [Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aws_s3_module.html) but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution posted by @Zeitounator should work :) . Just want to add what I have tested. Please check if this works for you.

```yaml
- name: Simple GET URL operation
  aws_s3:
    bucket: "{{ bucket_name }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ var_aws_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ var_aws_secret_key }}"
    object: "{{ dir1 }}/{{ filename }}"
    expiration: 10800
    mode: geturl
  register: url_output
```

Here

> bucket_name : is the name of the bucket

> object: is the key-for-the-object

> expiration: is the expiration time for the URL in seconds

The rest of the values are self explainatory.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an S3 access to test against.... but from what I can see in the documentation and more specifically in the [return values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aws_s3_module.html#return-values), you should be able to transform any `get` existing example, e.g.

```yaml
- name: Simple geturl operation
  aws_s3:
    bucket: mybucket
    object: /my/desired/key.txt
    mode: geturl
  register: geturl_result

- name: Use result
  debug:
   msg: >-
     The url for the latest geturl operation is {{ geturl_result.url }}
     and is valid for the next {{ geturl_result.expiry }} seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

For usage with multiples files:

```
- name: Get S3 URL Authentified
  aws_s3:
    bucket: "{{ aws_s3_bucket }}"
    object: "{{ item.value }}"
    mode: geturl
  loop: "{{ aws_files | dict2items}}"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  register: geturl_result

- name: Define aws_urls
  set_fact:
    aws_urls: |-
      { {% for value in geturl_result.results %}'{{ value.item.key }}': '{{ value.url }}',{% endfor %} }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).